# Project Euler 2 in Java

Tags: java

```
public class Euler2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int Num1 = 0;
        int Num2 = 1;
        int sum = 0;

        do
        {
            sum = Num1 + Num2;
            Num1 = Num2;
            Num2 = sum;

            if (Num2 % 2 == 0)
                sum = sum + Num2;
        }
        while (Num2 < 4000000);

        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

Each new term in the Fibonacci sequence is generated by adding the previous two terms. By starting with 1 and 2, the first 10 terms will be:

1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, ...

By considering the terms in the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not exceed four million, find the sum of the even-valued terms.

I don't feel like I coded it wrong but the answer I'm getting is 5702887 and I know it should be 4613732.

Comment: Are you trying to code some kind of established math formula? If so please state what it is. Otherwise, clearly explain what your program is supposed to be doing.

Comment: Each new term in the Fibonacci sequence is generated by adding the previous two terms. By starting with 1 and 2, the first 10 terms will be:

1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, ...

By considering the terms in the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not exceed four million, find the sum of the even-valued terms. 

this is what i'm trying to show in code.

Comment: dude the whole point of project euler is to solve the problems yourself.  it is immensely rewarding when you get one after hours of work (they get much harder).  It's also really cool to see people's solutions in the forum once you've solved it.  Note that project euler requests that people not share how to solve particular problems online because it can take the joy out of it for everyone (projecteuler.com/about once you've logged in).  happy programming!

Comment: sorry i really wasn't trying to get free answers just a little bit of insight on where i was wrong, his hints helped me out a lot and i won't reveal the true answer once i get it.

Comment: Have you tried walking through your code with the debugger?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public class Euler {
   public static void main(String[] args) {    
    int num1 = 0;
    int num2 = 1;
    int temp = 0;
    int sum = 0;

    do {
        if (num2 % 2 == 0) {
            sum = sum + num2;
        }
        temp = num1 + num2;
        num1 = num2;
        num2 = temp;
    } while (num2 < 4000000);

    System.out.println(sum);
  }
}
```

You messed up the sum by assigning it twice on each iteration where num2 is even. In this solution we use a temporary variable to store the next fibonacci number.

**Solution** = 4613732

Comment: Doesn't this require `num2++;` to increment the value? When run without `num2++;`, it's giving me `257114`. And if I run it with `num2++`, it's giving me `574906`. In both these cases, I am not getting `4613732`. Please correct me if I'm wrong..

Comment: Why would you want to increment num2? Try to run the code, it returns the correct result, 4613732.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, using:

- `while` instead of `do-while`
- `bits` operation instead of `%`
- only 2 variables to keep the effective values (no `aux`):

  ```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      int sum = 0 ;
      int x1 = 1;
      int x2 = 2;
      while ( x1 < 4000000 ) {
          if ( (x1 & 1) == 0 ){    // x % 2 == 0
              sum += x1;
          }
          x2=x1+x2;                // x2 = sum
          x1=x2-x1;                // x1 = the old value of x2
      }
      System.out.println(sum);
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

```
public void execute() {
        int total = 1;
        int toBeAdded = 1;
        int limit = 4000000;
        int totalSum = 0;
        int temp = 0;
        while (total <= limit) {
            if (total % 2 == 0) {
                totalSum = totalSum + total;
            }
            temp = toBeAdded;
            toBeAdded = total;
            total = toBeAdded + temp;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the program is supposed to do but part of the problem may be that you are assigning num2 to the value of sum before your if statement, making the inside of that if statement equivalent to sum = sum + sum;

On another note it is bad practice to capitalize the names of your local variables.
Good luck!

Comment: when i declare it after the if statement i end up with 4052018

Answer (score 0):

Here are some hints (and not a complete answer since this appears to be homework):

- When doing Fibonacci, you need to provide the first two terms as 1 and 2, not 0 and 1 as you are now.
- The `if (Num2 % 2 == 0)` means that, as user2573153 pointed out, the value of `sum` is getting doubled everytime `Num2` is even. But this isn't how Fibonacci works. I can see that you're trying to continuously sum up the even terms by using that `if` statement. So how can you do that without messing up `sum`? (Hint: store up the even numbers somewhere else).

Answer (score 0):

I just made it and I can only tell you that you need an if(... % 2 == 0){} and only sum up the even numbers.... I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you...

```
#include<stdio.h>
int  main()
{
    int i,a = 0,b = 1,temp = 0,sum = 0;
    while(temp < 4000000)
    {
        temp = a + b;
        printf("%d\n",temp);
        a = b;
        b = temp;
        if(temp % 2 == 0)
        {
            sum = sum + temp;
        }
    }
    printf("The sum is :- %d\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class FibonacciUpto4Million {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a=1, b=2;
        int sum = 0;
        while(b <= 4000000) {
            //swap two variables
            a = a+b;
            b = a-b;
            a = a-b;

            if(a%2 == 0) {
                sum = sum + a;
            }

            //make b = a+b;
            b = a+b;
        }
        if(b % 2 == 0 && b <= 30) {
            sum = sum + b;
        }
        System.out.println(sum); //4613732
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int n1=0;
    int n2=1; 
    int n3=0; 
    int count=10000; 
    int limit=4000000; 
    int sum=0;
    for(int i=1;(i<=count && n3<=limit); i++)
    {
        n3=n1+n2;
        if(n3%2==0){
            sum = sum+n3;
            System.out.println(sum);
        }
        n1=n2;
        n2=n3;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: This arrives at the answer the OP is seeking.

Answer (score -2):

**JavaScript**:

```
function printSumOfEvenFiboNumbersWithin (limit) {
    var current = 2, prev = 1, next, sum = 0;
    do {
        next = current + prev;
        prev = current;
        current = next;
        sum += prev % 2 == 0 ? prev : 0;
    } while (prev < limit);

    console.log(sum);
}
```

**`printSumOfEvenFiboNumbersWithin(4000000); // 4613732`**